# How to conditionally render in a react component with state updated in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In react I have a private route component that has an `isAuthenticated` state value that is used to either render the component it is wrapping, or redirect back to my login page.

In order to detect a refresh and perform an authentication check, I added a `useEffect` hook in the hope that I could check the authentication status, then update `isAuthenticated`, then either return the component or redirect accordingly.

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<IPrivateRouteProps> = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = React.useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        authService.getIdentity().then(response => {
            if (response) {
                dispatch(signIn(new Identity(response.account)));
                setIsAuthenticated(true);
            } else {
                setIsAuthenticated(false);
            }         
        });
    }, [])

    return isAuthenticated ? (
        <Route {...props} component={props.component} render={undefined} />
    ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: props.redirectPath }} />
    );
};
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work and I'm not sure why or how to solve it.

The value of `isAuthenticated` is always false at the point of rendering and I get the following error in the console....

```
index.js:1 Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in PrivateRoute (at App.tsx:23)
```

I can confirm that it does flow through to `setIsAuthenticated(true)` but this is never reflected in the value of `isAuthenticated` before rendering.

How can/should I solve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is that the first time that the code run, it evaluates the render with isAuthenticated false, then the useEffect kicks in and tries to update the value but you have been already redirected to another page.

I will suggest to use another variable to know if the authentication has been validated, and only continue after the authentication has been done.

```
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<IPrivateRouteProps> = (props) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = React.useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        authService.getIdentity().then(response => {
            if (response) {
                dispatch(signIn(new Identity(response.account)));
                setIsAuthenticated(true);
            } else {
                setIsAuthenticated(false);
            }
            setLoading(false);         
        });
    }, [])

    if (isLoading) {
        //we are not ready yet
       return null;
    }

    return isAuthenticated ? (
        <Route {...props} component={props.component} render={undefined} />
    ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: props.redirectPath }} />
    );
};
```

Comment: Interesting. It does work but I just need to be clear on how. I've never seen an if statement outside a hook or a method before in a react functional component. So, first time the component is loaded, it will return `null` from `if (isLoading)` before the async operation in `useEffect` has finished. When `loading` changes to `false` after the async operation has finished, is `if (isLoading)` checked again? Ta

Comment: Anyone can explain what is the rationale for use of another variable to know if the authentication has been validated? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you can see it says `Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.`.
To prevent this issue, can you plz try to put `<Route>` and `<Redirect>` inside of `<React.Fragment>` like this?

```
return isAuthenticated ? (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Route {...props} component={props.component} render={undefined} />
    </React.Fragment>
) : (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: props.redirectPath }} />
    </React.Fragment>
);
```